# How to enable KVM on gnome-boxes?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, gnome-boxes

I've been trying to work out why Windows 10 in gnome boxes is slow, and noticed gnome-boxes seems can't connect to KVM in libvirsh

```
(gnome-boxes:9264): Boxes-WARNING **: 17:14:11.078: util-app.vala:330: Failed to execute child process ?restorecon? (No such file or directory)
• The CPU is capable of virtualization: yes
• The KVM module is loaded: yes
• Libvirt KVM guest available: no
• Boxes storage pool available: no
    Could not get “gnome-boxes” storage pool information from libvirt. Make sure “virsh -c qemu:///session pool-dumpxml gnome-boxes” is working.
• The SELinux context is default: no

Report bugs to <http://gitlab.gnome.org/gnome/gnome-boxes/issues>.
Boxes home page: <https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes>.
```

KVM is available:

```
kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

libvirt is started:

```
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-09 17:02:32 BST; 13min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           https://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 5069 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 32768)
   Memory: 40.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─5069 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
           ├─7161 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
           └─7165 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper

Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq[7161]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq-dhcp[7161]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.122.2 -- 192.168.122.254, lease time 1h
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq-dhcp[7161]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface virbr0
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq[7161]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq[7161]: using nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq[7161]: read /etc/hosts - 32 addresses
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq[7161]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Apr 09 17:02:32 computer dnsmasq-dhcp[7161]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Apr 09 17:02:38 computer dnsmasq[7161]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 09 17:02:38 computer dnsmasq[7161]: using nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
```

I'm in the KVM group:

```
groups                                                                                                                                            
stu adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev input lpadmin sambashare docker kvm libvirt libvirtd realtime
```

I'm not sure what to try next ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

Fixed it by installing `libvirt-clients` I think.

`sudo apt install libvirt-clients`

Comment: This works on Debian 12.